# Delphi indy streaming Http Server

Tags: delphi, http, camera, indy

A camera captures an image.
I want this picture to be available via HTTP.
Can I somehow use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event to display it?
I just want to display the image live in a `TImage`.
If so, how?

Comment: Apologies, but I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask. First of all, what do you mean by "captures the image to the image"?

Comment: I would like to display the image of image1 on the Internet for the help http server

Comment: So is this a VCL forms application with a `TImage` control? I'm only guessing. That only clarifies 10% of your question though.

Comment: So I vcl Timage and wants to display a picture of him on the side. By means of Http server

Comment: Which side is the client and which side is the server? Are you trying to send the image from server to client or from client to server? Remember, no one here can read your mind.

Comment: Sorry for my English I use a translator to help ..., ".HTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
 AResponseInfo.ContentText:= Image1.Bitmap "He wants the server was just the camera image or Timage. ,Entered localhost in your browser and shows me a picture from the camera live

Comment: I still don't understand. I do understand that you're trying to transmit an image from the camera over the network/internet using HTTP. What I don't understand is everything else: What code do you already have? What format is this image? Is it the server or client which is sending the image? Are you trying to stream video? How does `HTTPServer1CommandGet` have to do with your question?

Comment: The rest is up to what we assume. I'm assuming that you're sending the image from a camera into an HTTP client socket, and receiving that on the server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to display the latest image when a client asks for it, you can do something like this:

```
type
  TGetImageStream = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    FStream: TStream;
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    class procedure GetImage(Stream: TStream);
  end;

procedure TGetImageStream.DoSynchronize;
begin
  Form1.Image1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(FStream);
end;

class procedure TGetImageStream.GetImage(Stream: TStream);
begin
  with Create do
  try
    FStream := Stream;
    Synchronize;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TGetImageStream.GetImage(Strm);
    Strm.Position := 0;
  except
    Strm.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'image/bmp';
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := Strm;
end;
```

But if you need to do live streaming of the camera images in real time, that gets a bit trickier.  You can do it a few different ways.  For instance, using a client pull:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document = '' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.Redirect('/');
  end
  else if ARequestInfo.Document = '/' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
    AResponseIno.ContentText := '<html>'+EOL+
                                '<head>'+EOL+
                                '<title>Camera Image</title>'+EOL+
                                '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content=5>'+EOL+
                                '</head>'+EOL+
                                '<body>'+EOL+
                                '<img src="/image">'+EOL+
                                '</body>'+EOL+
                                '</html>'+EOL;
  end
  else if ARequestInfo.Document = '/image' then
  begin
    Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      TGetImageStream.GetImage(Strm);
      Strm.Position := 0;
    except
      Strm.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'image/bmp';
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := Strm;
  end else begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
  end;
end;
```

Using a server push instead:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=imgboundary';
    AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := False;
    AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;

    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('--imgboundary');
    repeat
      Strm.Clear;
      TGetImageStream.GetImage(Strm);

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Content-type: image/bmp');
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Strm);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('--imgboundary');

      Sleep(5000);
   until False;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! , You helped me, I am only a beginner in programming, wants to learn from the best ;)

Comment: And as a separate application to receive this image to Timage?

Comment: webbrowser.navigate('localhost');? wants to be with another application were you can peep picture

Comment: If you want to make an application to receive the image, simply have it make the HTTP request instead of using a browser. Since you are already using Indy's `TIdHTTPServer` for the server, you can use Indy's `TIdHTTP` for the client: `IdHTTP1.Get('http://localhost/image', Strm); Strm.Position := 0; Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Strm);`. Or there are plenty of other third party components/libraries available that support HTTP - ICS, Synapse, libcurl, WinInet/WinHTTP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remy, the WriteHeader seems to write "Content-Length: 0"
It does work as intended - but if you manually write the header and exclude the Content-Length then it works

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.  It should have been posted as a comment instead.